# How to perform a 70/30 holdout in R

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I'm trying to make a prediction based on the below linear regression model:

[image]

I want to predict my intercept (market share) based on this formula given a value for each of the response variables. What is my formula from these results and can I just plug numbers in for each variable?

Or do I need to do holdout/training sets first?

EDIT: Added text of results.

```
summary(fit2)

Call:
lm(formula = Headache_Panel_Cleaned$Private_Label_Cleaned ~ Income_cleaned + 
    Age_Cleaned + Education_Cleaned, data = Headache_Panel_Cleaned)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-53.880 -33.804  -5.473  32.589  68.171 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       52.02867    0.96849  53.721   <2e-16 ***
Income_cleaned    -0.22711    0.01199 -18.949   <2e-16 ***
Age_Cleaned       -0.11363    0.01334  -8.516   <2e-16 ***
Education_Cleaned  0.13104    0.01213  10.807   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 35.09 on 38115 degrees of freedom
  (8224 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.0102,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.01012 
F-statistic:   131 on 3 and 38115 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: You should probably ask this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But your regression is `y = 52.02 -
 0.22711*Income_cleaned - 0.11363*Age_Cleaned + 0.13104*Education_Cleaned`. You'd get a "predicted" value based on this formula alone, which you can compare to a test set.

Comment: It would help to see all of the summary output (and as text, not an image). As @csgroen points out, the intercept is part of the formula, not the variable you are predicting. You should also check that the assumptions behind linear regression are satisfied. Note the low r-squared: this regression only explains about 1% of your variance.

Comment: In terms of test/training: you can do that to validate the model, but it isn't required for prediction. If you want to do validation, look at the [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) or [pipelearner](https://github.com/drsimonj/pipelearner) packages.

Comment: @neilfws added the summary output

Comment: In the `lm` formula, the response variable should be just be `Private_Label_Cleaned`, not `Headache_Panel_Cleaned$Private_Label_Cleaned`. Doesn't affect the output in this case, but a better way to write it.

Comment: If you're just trying to use this fit to predict response values given regressors, can you use `predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(Income_cleaned=..., ...))`? (with pertinent values included)